# llvm version 11 and librosa error

Tags: pi-3, python, software-installation, raspberry-pi-os, llvm

Best regards i need to download librosa to raspberry pi so first of all i downloaded virtualenv and created environment and installed llvm with:

```
sudo apt-get install llvm
pip3 install llvmlite==0.37
numpy==1.20.3
pip3 install numba==0.54.1
```

then i created python script with:

```
touch main.py
```

and imported librosa in script

```
import librosa
```

when i run script it gives me an error:

**RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xf but this version of numpy is 0xe**
and
**ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import**

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try pointing LLVM to the installation:

```
LLVM_CONFIG=/user/bin/llvm-config pip3 install llvmlite==0.37.0
```

You might need to run it with sudo (sudo pip3 install ...).